# eCommerce product is not found in my Facebook Developer Account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I read that article https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/app-dashboard which says I can create a test eCommerce account by using eCommerce product in my Facebook app. You can see the product highlighted in the image attached:

[image]

But when I open my dashboard the product isn't showing. I read shop feature is only available in the USA. I also used the VPN to change my location to USA but the product still not showing. Looking forward to your help, thanks!